# printf error can't launch java eclipse

Tags: java, compiler-errors

My `printf` contains an error. The rest of my code is done, but because of the error in my `printf`, I can't launch Java. Please help. My main class already done.

```
package id.web.aditya;

public class Roda {

private int diameter;
private String warna;
private String Merk;
private String Keterangan;

public String getMerk() {
    return Merk;
}
public void setMerk(String merk) {
    Merk = merk;
}

public int getDiameter() {
    return diameter;
}
public void setDiameter(int diameter) {
    this.diameter = diameter;
}
public String getWarna() {
    return warna;
}
public void setWarna(String warna) {
    this.warna = warna;
}


public String getKeterangan() {
    return Keterangan;
}
public void setKeterangan(String keterangan) {
    this.Keterangan = keterangan;
}

public void tampilanKeterangan(){
    System.out.printf("Roda %s Merk: %s Warna: %s Diameter: %d \n ", 
            Keterangan, Merk, warna, diameter);
}


public void Berhenti(){
    tampilanKeterangan();
    System.out.println("Kurangi Kecepatan");
    System.out.println("mulai berhenti..");
    System.out.println("Akhirna berhenti");
    System.out.println("--------------------");

}
public void berputar(){
    tampilanKeterangan();
    System.out.println("mulai berputar");
    System.out.println("berputar");
    System.out.println("berputar makin cepat");
    System.out.println("----------------------");
}

}
```

---

```
package id.web.aditya;

public class Mobil {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Roda rodaUntukDitest = new Roda();
    rodaUntukDitest.setDiameter(80);
    rodaUntukDitest.setMerk("Achiles");
    rodaUntukDitest.setWarna("Hitam");
    rodaUntukDitest.setKeterangan("");
    rodaUntukDitest.Berhenti();
    rodaUntukDitest.berputar();
}

}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem: The method printf(Locale, String, Object[]) in the type
>   PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, String,
>   String, String, int)

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method printf(Locale, String, Object[]) in the type PrintStream is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String, String, int)

Comment: at tampilan Keterangan

Comment: which jdk version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

String format feature is introduced in java 1.5. You are apparently using a java version or a compilation option prior to that version.
If you are using eclipse open the project properties (ALT + Enter on the project).  Look at the tab java compiler.

[image: Eclipse Properties]

Here you can set your compiler compliance level. You probably have a newer java version installed. In this case eclipse shows you the above mention error.

I would expect to show you something like "The method printf(String, String, String, String, Integer) is undefined for the type PrintStream". but it doesn't so this might be a little bit confusing.

Comment: If he was using < 1.5 he wouldn't have [`printf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf(java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) at all.